# Is the mass of antimatter negative or positive?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Is the mass of antimatter negative or positive For example, the mass of the electron 9.1×10^(-31), does this mean that the mass of the positron -9.1×10^(-31)?

Comment: This would be better on Physics where indeed it has been answered several times : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241060/what-is-the-current-status-of-measurement-of-the-gravitational-mass-of-antimatte https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394502/is-it-true-that-matter-and-antimatter-must-have-same-mass  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249459/   The answer is matter and antimatter have the same positive mass (inertial and gravitational) although this is not empirically proven for gravitational mass.

Comment: This is an interesting question and in fact so interesting that folks are working hard to measure the *gravitational* mass of antiparticles. In [What is the Current Status of Measurement of the Gravitational Mass of Antimatter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241060/83380) I mention some of the work and answers address the status a few years ago and answers to the earlier [Has the gravitational interaction of antimatter ever been examined experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/83380) summarize previous work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Astronomy but instead about more fundamental aspects of matter. It would be on-topic in Physics, but as comments (and answer(s)) show it's already been addressed there.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question and in fact so interesting that folks are working hard to measure the *gravitational* mass of antiparticles. In  [What is the Current Status of Measurement of the Gravitational Mass of Antimatter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241060/83380) I mention some of the work and answers address the status a few years ago and answers to the earlier [Has the gravitational interaction of antimatter ever been examined experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/83380) summarize previous work.

See in CERN News:

- November 2018: [New antimatter gravity experiments begin at CERN](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/new-antimatter-gravity-experiments-begin-cern)
- March 2021: [ALPHA cools antimatter using laser light for the first time](https://home.cern/news/press-release/experiments/alpha-cools-antimatter-using-laser-light-first-time)

It is generally believed that antimatter will have the same sign and magnitude of gravitational mass as "normal" matter but the last word of [@AnnaV's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/241181/83380) is... "Patience" :-) We have to wait a little longer for careful, precision measurements. Handling antimatter is already hard, and suspending anti-hydrogen for long periods of time requires ultrahigh vacuum, lasers, and patience.